# Starcraft II Email Problems

Tags: battle.net

I recently had trouble with my email account, being told it was trying to be accessed by another person. I had no trouble with anything else until a week or so later when I suddenly couldn't log into to SC II. I can't submit a support ticket because I'm unable to log into to my battle.net account and I can't change anything for the same reason. Is there anything besides calling the help line to Blizzard to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9):

Be careful, it might be spam, I get several "your account has been hacked" emails each week. purportedly from Blizzard, but they are not.

In this case, it does look like you have actually been hacked (possibly because you went to that link?)

In that case, you will need to contact Blizzard account support.

You can [unlock](https://us.battle.net/account/support/password-reset.html?requestType=UNLOCK_ACCOUNT) your account if it's locked, or [begin account recovery](https://us.battle.net/account/support/identify-account.html) on the battle.net website.

If all else fails, you can always try [talking to someone at Blizzard](https://us.battle.net/support/en/ticket/submit).

Comment: I don't think this is the case, if they can't even sign in, then their account has definitely already been compromised.

Comment: But i cant even open my email account. Thats the problem. I would switch to a more reliable host (gmail) if i had the option, but i cant even open my inbox.

Comment: @turbo yeah, it looks like it is hacked, so I've updated with links to get him started.

Comment: @Brass_Dog I think the [begin account recovery](https://us.battle.net/account/support/identify-account.html) link is what you want.

Comment: @Brass_Dog Wait are you saying you can't access your e-mail account anymore?  You should be a little more concerned about that than your battle.net account...

Comment: Oh, it does look like he can't access his email account. In such a case I think the account recovery is where he needs to go. He'll probably need the original CD keys and copies of his driver's license (or equivalent ID)

Comment: I am concerned, and but i don't use the email for anything else other than recieving news updates and such. I rarely send emails myself. And as for these links, they all require me to login with my battle.net account, but thats not working because my email is not working/being hacked/borked.

Comment: what do you use for e-mail? you should look into recovering that account.

Comment: Unfortunately i use hotmail. Ive had the account for years and haven't switched to anything until recently. And with the account recovery link, i cant get the link its supposedly emailing my account because i can't get into my email.

Comment: @Brass_Dog So, I just added one more link which gives a link to contact customer support.

Comment: Ill give them a call then. Thank you all for you help. Heres to hoping it gets resolved swiftly.

Comment: @brass_dog what happened when you contacted support?

Comment: @Brass_Dog you said you can not answer your email account either.... Did you have the same password for your battle.net account and your email address?  I know hackers will often check that and try to change it too.